# When delete key pressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end cannot negative. [end: -1]

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was building an app using the Jetpack Compose library, I had an `OutlinedTextField` composable and I accidently pressed the delete key on the keyboard. the cursor was at the end of the textfield. suddenly the app crashed.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end cannot negative. [end: -1]
```

this is understandable because there were no character to delete, but I dont want the app to crash, how do I fix this?

**Complete Error Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end cannot negative. [end: -1]
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRangeKt.packWithCheck(TextRange.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRangeKt.TextRange(TextRange.kt:37)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditingBuffer.delete$ui_text_release(EditingBuffer.kt:205)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.DeleteSurroundingTextCommand.applyTo(EditCommand.kt:271)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditProcessor.apply(EditProcessor.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.apply(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:62)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.access$apply(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:49)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:134)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.commandExecutionContext(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:211)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.process-ZmokQxo(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInputKt$textFieldKeyInput$2$1.invoke-ZmokQxo(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInputKt$textFieldKeyInput$2$1.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputModifier.propagateKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(KeyInputModifier.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputModifier.processKeyInput-ZmokQxo(KeyInputModifier.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:567)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchKeyEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:574)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1947)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchKeyEvent(Dialog.java:1126)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7365)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7191)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6595)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6786)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7007)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3624)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:3163)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:3154)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3601)
2022-05-06 22:09:32.416 3649-3649/io.gopiper.piper E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
2022-05-06 22:09:32.417 3649-3649/io.gopiper.piper D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-05-06 22:09:32.424 3649-3649/io.gopiper.piper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.gopiper.piper, PID: 3649
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end cannot negative. [end: -1]
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRangeKt.packWithCheck(TextRange.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRangeKt.TextRange(TextRange.kt:37)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditingBuffer.delete$ui_text_release(EditingBuffer.kt:205)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.DeleteSurroundingTextCommand.applyTo(EditCommand.kt:271)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditProcessor.apply(EditProcessor.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.apply(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:62)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.access$apply(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:49)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:134)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput$process$2.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.commandExecutionContext(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:211)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInput.process-ZmokQxo(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInputKt$textFieldKeyInput$2$1.invoke-ZmokQxo(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldKeyInputKt$textFieldKeyInput$2$1.invoke(TextFieldKeyInput.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputModifier.propagateKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(KeyInputModifier.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputModifier.processKeyInput-ZmokQxo(KeyInputModifier.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendKeyEvent-ZmokQxo(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:567)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchKeyEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:574)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1986)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1947)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchKeyEvent(Dialog.java:1126)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7365)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7191)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6595)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6786)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7007)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3624)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:3163)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:3154)
2022-05-06 22:09:32.425 3649-3649/io.gopiper.piper E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3601)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: This for sure shouldn't happen and doesn't happen in usual circumstances. You should start with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) it to the maintainers.

Comment: It's a bug in compose: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199919707